# Is it possible to hide the line & symbol next to Highcharts legend items?

Tags: highcharts

I have my legend aligned with my data series, so I don't want the little sample bit of line/symbol to show next to the legend item.

symbolWidth:0 obviously removes the symbool, but I'm still left with a few pixels of line.

I've looked in the reference guide and can't find any options to adjust this, which seems odd, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hide the symbols using [legend options](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend):

```
legend: {
    symbolPadding: 0,
    symbolWidth: 0,
    symbolHeight: 0,
    squareSymbol: false
},
```

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  legend: {
    symbolPadding: 0,
    symbolWidth: 0,
    symbolHeight: 0,
    squareSymbol: false
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }, {
    type: 'column',
    data: [95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b04woedh/1/

Comment: Thanks, perfect!  Seems odd there's not just an option for it though!

Comment: @Codemonkey To request a feature, please post a suggestion on [UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general) or vote for the ones that are already registered.

Comment: this example is nice..but this is written in jquery.How can we achieve the same functionality using angularjs.please help me..

Comment: @user1645290 API solution (pure JS): It's possible to hide legend symbols by setting their size to almost zero - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4tmzdsmL/42/

Comment: I believe doing `serie.legendSymbol.hide()` is better than destroying it. I got a javascript error after destroying this when trying to create a new chart after the initial one. It seems that Highcharts destroys elements before creating the new chart and failed when the legend symbol was already destroyed (`Cannot read property 'isSVG' of undefined at a.SVGElement.destroy (highcharts.src.js:4802)`).

Answer (score 9):

You can hide it simply using css.

This worked for me

Square and circle:

```
.highcharts-legend-item rect{
    display:none;
}
```

Line :

```
.highcharts-legend-item path {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This solution works highcharts-6. The accepted answer no longer works.

Answer (score 4):

One workout is by giving .001 to hide symbol

```
 legend: {
   symbolHeight: .001,
   symbolWidth: .001,
   symbolRadius: .001
 },
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/3oc87gsp/1/)